# Exporting GIS line vector data (roads) to R with intention to use it for network K-function

Tags: r, network-programming, shapefile, spatstat

I am still a beginner to R and I have the following problem. Any tips will be highly appreciated - it will be a big help to start off.
I have a road shapefile for one country in ArcGIS, that I would like to use as a network variable in R to apply network K-function (look for point randomness on the network using spatstat package). I have never worked with this type of problem before in R and I can't figure out how to convert the vector line dataset into network variable in R. I tried to used the shapefile package, but after reading the .shp, .shx and .dbf files, I don't know how it can be used any further.

Comment: As a starting point, please add to the question the code you have already written, preferably with a link to the shapefile. If you can make the question [fully reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that would be even better.

Comment: I have taken a cursory look at the `spatstat` package and it looks like you will need a `ppp` (point pattern) object. Even if you can extract the vector line set from the shapefile, how will you reduce or convert that to a set of points? Will you take a sample every 1km, for example? If you include all the points that make up the line of the roads surely you will have far too many, non-meaningful points? I do not know the answer to this, I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above are not correct.

In the `spatstat` package, first convert your shapefile to an object of class `"psp"` (planar segment pattern) as explained in the accompanying vignette on shapefiles.

Then use the function `as.linnet` to convert the `"psp"` object to a linear network object of class `"linnet"`.

For more explanation, see chapter 17 of [the spatstat book](https://www.crcpress.com/books/details/9781482210200/).